# передача массива в функцию по ссылке

Tags: c++, c++11

`void ShowData(int(&arr)[], int size);`

Эта запись означает передачу ссылки на начало массива, или на весь массив, как параметр?
Или нужно обязательно указывать `[size]` массива?
Или, как вообще можно корректно передать массив в функцию так, чтобы в нём отразились все изменения?

Comment: используйте вектор или std::array

Comment: Массивы обычно передают так `int * array`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Достаточно просто использовать указатель:

```
void ShowData(int *arr, int size);
```

То же самое можно записать в виде `void ShowData(int arr[], int size);` и `void ShowData(int arr[N], int size);`, но результат будет абсолютно такой же: arr будет указателем на `int`.

---

Если длина массива известна во время компиляции, тогда можно передавать именно ссылку на массив:

```
void ShowData(int(&arr)[N]);
```

Где `N` - константа времени компиляции. Как вариант, можно сделать `N` параметром шаблона:

```
template <std::size_t N> void ShowData(int(&arr)[N]) {/*здесь N - размер массива*/}
```

Обратите внимание: Если вы выделяли память динамически, и у вас есть не сам массив, а указатель на него, тогда чтобы передать его в `int(&arr)[N]` потребуется `reinterpret_cast`.

---

Причудливая конструкция, которую вы написали:

```
void ShowData(int(&arr)[], int size);
```

Дает тот же эффект*, что передача указателя, только интерфейс менее удобный: чтобы передать массив в такую функцию, придется использовать `reinterpret_cast<int(&)[]>(массив)`.

> Эта запись означает передачу ссылки на начало массива, или на весь массив, как параметр?

Я так понимаю, ни то, ни другое.

Это ссылка на тип `int[]`, но т.к. он считается incomplete type, переменные в принципе не могут иметь такой тип (в отличие от `int[N]`). Можно сказать, что вы передаете ссылку на несуществующий `int[]` с тем же адресом, что и ваш массив.

<sub>* Хотя возможно, что доступ к такому параметру приводит к нарушению strict aliasing (типы ведь отличаются) и неопределенному поведению, но нужно проверять стандарт.</sub>